# IsDate in TSQL Issue

Tags: t-sql

I have a bug on our app and it points that if there is a date format like this:

```
SELECT IsDate('4:27:01') -- ok
SELECT IsDate('25:01') ---> not ok
SELECT IsDate('23:01') ---> ok
```

In our data, sometimes the format only 5 characters which means it's only for minutes and seconds.

What is best way to handle this?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand exactly what you are asking here?

Comment: How do you currently distinguish `11:15` between 11 minutes and 15 seconds and 11:15am?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way might be to add "00:" when the length is 5 characters.
e.g. :

```
declare @str varchar(100)
set @str = '25:01'
-- if length is 5, interpret as  00:mi:ss
set @str = (CASE WHEN LEN(@str)=5 THEN '00:' + @str ELSE @str END)
select ISDATE(@str) -- shows 1
select cast(@str as time)  -- shows 00:25:01.000
```